# Greensock or any other Javascript lib in a dart project

Tags: dart, gsap, dart-editor, dart-js-interop

I've been trying unsuccessfully to use the Greensock JavaScript library in my new Dart projects. Any one has experience or can recommend me a guide or tutorial from dart where someone successfully uses an external JS lib ?

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried, so we can work it out from there? Code is important as part of a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Using JavaScript from Dart: The js Library](http://www.dartlang.org/articles/js-dart-interop/).

Comment: I tried it before asking here. Followed all steps with the goal of using Greensock but it did not worked.

Comment: I use `js` package for several js libraries without problem. Perhaps you should paste some code and what error you are facing.

Comment: Hello, can you please explain it more, I even dont quite get the tutorial on their webpage. https://github.com/greensock/GreenSock-JS/ I need TweenLite.js :)

Answer (score 1):

Just import the dart:js library, and then you would call greensock from Dart like this:

```
context['TweenMax'].callMethod("to",["#myDiv", 0.15, new JsObject.jsify({x:100})]);
```

When you import dart:js library, make sure you add interop.js to your HTML page as well below:

> ```
> <script src="packages/browser/interop.js"></script>
> ```